# Fix the aspect ratio of the first row in UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I'm creating a screen, imagine the facebook profile screen.. A tableview and the first cell is an image. The goal is that this image maintains an aspect ratio, so with different screen sizes I don't have to worry about sizing it..

I can't get this to work with any view, even if I set specific constraints, the cell won't set the correct height..

I have a little project showing constraints, in this link..

My VC Code:

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
}
```

My constrains:
[image]

Comment: Example is here: http://www.speedyshare.com/gP6UV/autoSizeCell.zip

Answer (score 1):

This is what you should do:

1. Insert a table view header view
2. Update the frame height keep the desired aspect ratio in the `viewWillLayoutSubviews` function.

[image]

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var headerView: UIView!

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        var frame = headerView.frame;
        // Check and see if the aspect ratio of the frame
        // of the header view is the desired aspect ratio.
        if frame.size.height != frame.width * 0.5 {
            // If it is not, update the frame
            frame.size.height = frame.width * 0.5;
            headerView.frame = frame;
            // reset the header view
            self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the height of the table view cell is basically a function of the table view's width, it might be easier to implement the heightForRowAtIndexPath delegate method to return the width of the table view multiplied by the ratio you want.  That would take constraints out of the picture entirely, and probably be more efficient.

Comment: That's a very good point, there may be other cells with different heights but from what I've seen I can return dynamic from the height method based on the indexPath. the image cell will have some label, which I've managed to get to work with auto layout.  More than anything , this is just frustating me because I feel like it should work as I'm expecting.